# UIView inside custom UITableViewCell wrong width / height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, constraints

I ran into the following problem. I have a custom class UITableViewCell with a few UIViews inside, which act as container for chartviews. 
The problem is if I do the following:

```
self.upperLeftChart = XYPieChart(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.upperLeftContainer.frame.width, self.upperLeftContainer.frame.height))
self.upperLeftContainer.addSubview(self.upperLeftChart)
```

The Chartview is as big as the whole UITableViewCell instead of the size of my container. 
If I print the size of my container

```
NSLog("\(self.upperLeftContainer.frame.width) / \(self.upperLeftContainer.frame.height)")
```

it prints: 320.0 / 568.0 which is wrong. My container is about a quarter of the whole cell.

I guess it hast something to do with my Autolayout + Constraints. If I set the size to 120x120px hardcoded, it works nicely.

Any trick to get the real width and height of UIView arranged with autolayout and constraints?

Comment: Btw, what is the size of upperLeftContainer?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to override

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.upperLeftCart.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.upperLeftContainer.frame.width, self.upperLeftContainer.frame.height)
}
```

That way it will change frame of the view every time cell resizes

Comment: not exactly the same thing, you only need to initialise view once, and set frame few times, layoutSubviews is going to be called more then once